# Motion Recognition Manager Fingerprint error

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, fingerprint

I tried to programming andorid application with fingerprint.
On emulator everything is OK.
But on Samsung Galaxy S6 (my only real device with fingerprint reader) my app is all black and on console I have this errors:

D/SensorManager: unregisterListener ::

D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null

D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null

W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/myPackage-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in myPackage rsrc of package myPackage

W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/myPackage-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in myPackage rsrc of package myPackage

W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for WSTaskFragment{14c3cd1 #1 cart1TaskFragment} not updated inline; expected state 1 found 0

W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for WSTaskFragment{2a3c336 #4 productListTaskFragment21561404} not updated inline; expected state 1 found 0

W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for WSTaskFragment{6f8c237 #5 cartListTaskFragment} not updated inline; expected state 1 found 0

D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager

E/MotionRecognitionManager: mSContextService = android.hardware.scontext.ISContextService$Stub$Proxy@309412b

E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@f0e0988

E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@f0e0988

D/Activity: performCreate Call Injection manager

D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : SecSettings2

D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{a9ad902 V.E...... R.....I. 0,0-0,0}

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I don´t sent a cancel signal to my FingerPrint namager.